# MVC ASPX server control in Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to convert a MVC aspx page into a Razor view.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="DotNetOpenAuth" Namespace="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Provider"
    TagPrefix="op" %>


<op:IdentityEndpoint ID="IdentityEndpoint11" runat="server" 
    ProviderEndpointUrl="~/OpenId/Provider" ProviderVersion="V11" />

<op:IdentityEndpoint ID="IdentityEndpoint20" runat="server" 
    ProviderEndpointUrl="~/OpenId/Provider" XrdsUrl="~/User/all/xrds" 
    XrdsAutoAnswer="false" XrdsAdvertisement="Both" />
```

How can this be done?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible.

If you really need to do this, you can put the control in an ASCX partial view and include it using `@Html.Partial`.